# Sending headers and POST data via NGINX to a secondary server asynchronously?

Tags: logging, asynchronous, nginx, analytics

I want to send the data received by NGINX to another server asynchronously without causing any delay in serving the request by NGINX.

Here is the detailed scenario:

User sent a request to my NGINX server which executes a script and shows the response.

In between this, I want to send the request data to another server so that I can manipulate and get decent logging and analytics.

NGINX should not wait for the response from this server and there should be no lag in serving the initial response user wanted.

Let me know if any further clarifications are required.

Answer (score 0):

To asynchronously send data to another server you can use [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/).

However, We have recently setup a system in which we used Beanstalkd. It proved to have some negative effect on the speed of working with incoming requests. Therefore we have made the decision to directly send the request to the other server. This worked more consistently.

Best regards,

Comment: Is the same requests hitting two servers directly ? If so, how have you achieved that ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you certainly want to forward the POST data, to the other server, I would look into using a script in PHP, Lua, Ruby... and do something like this (PHP-like):

```
$data = json_encode($_POST);
file_put_contents("/tmp/data.json", $data);
exec("log-data.sh&");
```

The `&` in the command line to the `exec()` command runs that command "in the background", detached from the current PHP instance. Here I show a shell script, it could be another PHP script, a C program, Lua, whatever you'd like.

The fact is that script does the strict minimum which is share the `$_POST` data and then run the script. (one important thing, though, the name `"/tmp/data.json"` needs to be dynamically generated otherwise when two simultaneous requests happen, the data of the first smash the data of the other, or even they both write to the file in concert...)

If you were planning to write your own nginx module, you would do the same thing. Your handler would save the POST data in a file and then you'd start a process with `fork()` + `exec()` to run another script, C program, whatnot in the background. This requires you to recompile nginx, though.